# Ensuring that javascript code was not modified

Tags: javascript

Let's say we have a small javascript code, something like this:

```
function calculate(input) {
      input = input + 100;
      // the code will send the result here to the server
}
```

As javascript code can be modified, any one can change the hard coded 100 that is in the function, to any number, thus modifying the end data that the server will receive.

Is there any way on the server, with which I can verify that the function that was run, was unmodified when it ran?

**USE-CASE**: I have some big calculations, that I would need to perform, and I was thinking about creating the code for these calculations in JS (which would slow them a bit down), but if I would give a good enough incentive(maybe a reward of money, or anything simmilar), for other people to use their computers in these calculations, calculate partial information and send it to me, I would need a lot less computing power, because the work would be shared between other computers.

The only way to solve this problem in this use-case at the moment, is to calculate part-jobs multiple times on multiple systems, and if the results do not match up, that would mean someone interfered with the calculation code, but if any one has a better idea, I am all ears:)

Comment: Assuming that you say about JS executed in a browser - no, there is no way to do this.

Comment: well, if you need this kind of validation you will have to handle it server side. There is no JavaScript code that runs on a browser, that the user potentially couldn't change

Comment: No, there isn't. It doesn't matter, anyway; they could just make a totally different request formed without invoking that function.

Comment: It is an interesting ask tho Adam. It would be cool if a tuple was returned with your result and a method hash.

Comment: @Bibberty why wouldn't someone who could interfere with the function definition also interfere with the hash?

Comment: They could also interfere with the code that *checks* the hash.

Comment: @Bibberty I was thinking something along these lines, like duplicating the unmodified original code to a string on the server, and hashing it, but then I would need to enforce somehow that the code that is sent to the server, contains the hash of the function that executed it, but someone can easily copy out the hash, and send it in a totally new function, so this wouldn't work:(

Comment: @Amy no, because that code is on the server, what they could do, is interfere with the code that generates the hash.

Comment: As a general rule, if security is a concern, you have to accept that everything that comes from the client is potentially compromised and there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yup fair comment.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery This. 60-70% of bad data comes from the client due to unintentional mistakes. another 25% comes from the client due to malicious intent. 5% comes from server-side errors. So if you're getting data from the client, never trust it. This is part of the reason eval() is so widely hated and discouraged: because people use it to execute user data, which is NO.

Comment: With regard to the updated information: what stops me from bombing your endpoint with random data to get the reward? You would need to validate my calculations, i.e. calculate it again, which doesn't bring any improvement whatsoever. The idea about checking other people's calculations is pretty good and reminds me of cryptocurrency, but it is still vulnerable to a 51% attack.

Comment: Try and think of a website as a user-interface only, keyboard, mouse, input.  etc.  Never ever, do any business logic client side, unless that logic can be duplicated an validated again server-side,.. eg.  If you  were to have a shopping basket, you could maybe calculate the basket total client side, but the real total, (the one to be trusted), will be server side only.

Comment: I mean there's nothing stopping the user from not running your code at all and sending back an arbitrary result. Even encryption would not help, since client would need to decrypt to run, they'd need the key for that, etc. I'd say uglify the code as best you can and accept the risk.

Comment: What you could do to police is random assertion of correct values with a trusted system... blacklist people with bad answers. If that's possible, the actual calcs are not offered to us.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev we are not talking about big money here, the bigger problem will be, that probably very few users will join in the calculation, and not a 51% attack:) Once again, this would be for a board game, and the reward would be a discounted price anyways, so I am not affraid, that someone will maliciously send me bad data for the reward only, but there are people, who do these kind of things, just for the fun of it

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the relationship between a board game and distributed computations...

Comment: @Herohtar we are trying to implement an AI which calculates the least number of moves required to beat the enemy. There are tons of possible fights, and we want to use this AI to set the health/armor values of the enemies, so that we ensure each fight is 1. winnable, 2. winnable in a reasonable amount of time. We could do all of this manually,but what we plan to do, is instead of testing 10s of different health/armor/x combinations of monsters manually, we use the program until we find an adecvate value, and then manually test only THAT value, to see if the program indeed gives correct answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I mean, the server has no way of knowing how its data was calculated, so this isn't really a thing usually. If you need to verify the legitimacy of data, you should be doing the calculations on the server instead of visibly on the client.

If you want to make sure the function isn't changed via the console or something, you can assign it to a constant and freeze it: `const calculate = Object.freeze(function(input) { /* code here...  */ });`

But that doesn't in any way guarantee someone hasn't just sent the data on their own and bypassed your function altogether, so this is a terrible idea. I'd like to reiterate that just to be clear: *this is a terrible idea.* Do sensitive calculations on the server, not the client.

**EDIT** Your update sounds an awful lot like a use case for a blockchain...

Comment: This wouldn't help me, unfortunately. I will update the question with the use-case for what I need this for.

Comment: What if I `freeze` 2 functions, as constants, one that retrieve the data from the server that needs to be processed, together with a hash, and another that calculates, and sends back the original hash to the server. If a functons is freezed as a constant on page run, can no one change that function?

Comment: No one can change the function, but they can easily write their own function to send whatever data they want, and they can always access the data your server sends to them. So they can just write a 2-line script to send false data back to the server with the correct hash. There's no way to do what you want on the client side.

Comment: I am not trying to create a new blockchain:) This will be for a game that I am making:)

Comment: I'm not suggesting creating a new blockchain. I'm suggesting you use an existing blockchain library.

Comment: I would like to make this as easy as possible for the people who will help in the calculation, I mean, like just "put in the url in your browser, leave it on for a few minutes, and you are done" easy:)

Comment: @IceMetalPunk  `No one can change the function,`  They can change whatever they like.  Even no need to create another function, get the current function and modify to suit your hacking needs.. :)

Comment: @Keith Does `Object.freeze()` not work on functions? I've never used it for that purpose, but I tested to ensure it didn't throw any errors, and it doesn't.

Comment: @AdamBaranyai You want a level of security that client-visible code just can't achieve, on the client, without any extra verification by the user? I'm sorry, but I think you're asking for too much, in that there's no way to do something with those restrictions. Security comes with extra effort; either that's on your part and it's done on the server, or that's on the user's part and they need to do more than enter a URL.